# Can I use BeautifulSoup and Selenium together at the same time?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a website for information pertaining to products. I need to log in to access the products I have access to. After successfully logging in and navigating to the product details page, Selenium returns nothing. I have been trying for the past week and nothing worked out.

So, I was wondering if I can try BeautifulSoup to get the text that I want after reaching that point?

Is it doable? Please reccomend any resources/readings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960326/how-can-i-parse-a-website-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197425/navigate-with-selenium-and-scrape-with-beautifulsoup-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475675/how-to-scrape-hidden-class-data-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529849/python-scraping-javascript-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a website using Selenium and Beautifulsoup in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13960326/how-can-i-parse-a-website-using-selenium-and-beautifulsoup-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, the HTML of the page is available within Selenium using the [`.page_source`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) property, you can pass the HTML to `BeautifulSoup` to parse it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes very much, You can integrate both of them **Beautiful soup** and **Selenium**

Selenium is for automating browser which means UI

and Beautiful soup is a **HTML parser.**

But Selenium is quite powerful, you should be able to continue with UI.

Selenium - [Official docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

BeautifulSoup - [Official docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 0):

use `driver.get(url)` to open url which is found by bs4 (convert from bs4 to selenium)

use `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")` to crawl all page which is opened by selenium (convert from selenium to bs4)

but this is a problem I have found for a long time:
use `BeautifulSoup(element.get_attribute('innerHTML'), "html.parser")`  to crawl element which is found by selenium (convert from selenium to bs4)